# Java Fx whole Application in fullscreen

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen

I want to create an Fullscreen Application on an RasperryPI.

But now i have a problem with the fullscreen mode, because everytime if I switch sites I must set the FullSreen property false and then true otherwise the window won't get fullscreen.
But if I switch the site the window is shortly not fullscreen and the it is fullscreen.

```
SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
splitPane.getItems().addAll(table,vbLayout);

Scene scene = SceneBuilder.create().root(splitPane). build();
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
primaryStage.sizeToScene();
primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
```

I hope you understand what i mean.

Best wishes

Johannes

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to switch sites when you are in fullscreen mode. If you are able to, you must first stop it. The user must come back to normal mode before doing anything else or you must force the normal mode. It's just like playing a video on fullscreen mode on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Follwing Code:-
I Have Use Rectangle 2D Class

```
SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(); 
splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
splitPane.getItems().addAll(table,vbLayout);
 Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();  
 Scene scene = SceneBuilder.create().root(splitPane). build();
 scence.setWidth(primScreenBounds.getWidth());
 scence.setHeight(primScreenBounds.getHeight())
 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
 primaryStage.show();
```